Issue with Expo-AV: Sound Recorded During Screen Recording
I’m experiencing an issue with Expo-AV in my React Native project. When a user starts a screen recording on iOS, the screen turns black as expected (due to expo-screen-capture), but the audio continues to be recorded.
I need help finding a solution to prevent the audio from being recorded when screen recording is initiated.
expo-screen-capture

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
